# Create Date variable, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, variables

I am trying to create a variable that I can use to compare a date column in one of my tables. I know for a fact that this date exists but I am not getting any results but no error messages either. Here is what I have:

```
VAR TEST_DATE Char(10)
EXEC SELECT '06/20/1989' INTO :TEST_DATE FROM DUAL;
SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
FROM MEMBER
INNER JOIN PERS ON MEMBER.ID = PERS.ID
WHERE PERS.DATEBIRTH = TO_DATE(:TEST_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a record which has DOB as 06/20/1989. Try using >  or < operator to see if any record are coming

Comment: I got results using: or Pers.DateBirth = '06/20/1989'. So does that mean that there is something wrong with my variable format? If so, I can't point it out.

Comment: Is the column in your table of type `DATE`, or is it a string? Do you actually have a matching record in `MEMBER`?

Comment: If you got the results with condition Pers.DateBirth = '06/20/1989' then I suspect that Pers.DateBirth is of type String not Date. So in order for your above query to work convert Pers.DateBirth to Date format using TO_DATE(Pers.DateBirth,'MM/DD/YYYY'). Try and let me know if working

Comment: Thanks for your help all, but I found out that I kept hitting 'Run Statement' when I had to use 'Run Script'...sorry. It works fine, I'm just new to Oracle. I can already tell I am going to drive myself crazy with the little differences.

Comment: PERS.DATEBIRTH may not be a truncated date, while :TEST_DATE always is truncated.

Answer (score 1):

If DATEBIRTH contains hours/minutes, this is how to compare with date only type of DATE variables:

```
SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
FROM MEMBER
INNER JOIN PERS ON MEMBER.ID = PERS.ID
WHERE TRUNC(PERS.DATEBIRTH) = TO_DATE(:TEST_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```